# When to use managedobjectcontext reset, how to use it safely

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am using the CoreData guru Marcus Zara multi-context asynchronous saving approach.[Asynchronous Saving](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/)

And I found out that as there are 3 contexts involved, and I got 3 times of instances being created when I do fetch with the lowest child context and then up to the context that linked to the coordinator.

Other than that, I not sure whether this is the valid statement, when fetching the entity object it will also fetch out the linked entity object.(Do let me know if anyone has any ideal.)

In my case, I got User to Message (one-to-many relationship)in my persistent store and I just want to get one User object in fetch and assign it in new Message object creating. In the end, a new Message object is successfully created in the persistent store but turn out i got in the memory via Debug memory graph:
User(3) one-to-many Message(500 * 3 = 1500)

**QUESTION:**

Is this the right scenario I can use ManagedObjectContext.reset for 3 contexts to clear off all the unwanted instances in the memory? and if yes, how to use it safely as cleaning the main context might also affect other concurrent private context in saving. if no, when managedobjectcontext designed to be used?

Thanks in advance!!!